# Why does a typical 88 key piano keyboard start on 'A' and end on 'C'?

Tags: piano

A typical 88 key piano keyboard starts on 'A' and ends on 'C'.

- Why?

Comment: So we can play keys of C major and A minor quite easily - no sharps or flats!